# Can not run Sys.dm_exec_requests during backup restore

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, dmv

We do database creation through an application,i am  seeing below error when running below DMV(connection context is master)

**query ran :**

```
SELECT session_id as SPID,wait_type,wait_resource,last_wait_type,
 command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r with(nolock)  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a 
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

**Error thrown :**

```
Msg 927, Level 14, State 6, Line 5
Database 'XXXXXX' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.
```

Please Note this works some times and it fails some times with above error...when it works wait type is `PREEMPTIVE_OS_CREATEFILE` if this helps

Any ideas on why DMV throws this error.I expected DMV to work.

**SQl version:**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU10-GDR) (KB4052725) - 12.0.5571.0 (X64) 
    Jan 10 2018 15:52:08 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

**SSMS related info:**

```
   Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                       12.0.5571.0
    Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    12.0.5571.0
    Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.3.9600.17415
    Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
    Microsoft Internet Explorer         9.11.9600.19541
    Microsoft .NET Framework            4.0.30319.42000
    Operating System                    6.3.9600
```

**screenshot for error:**
[image]

restore command ran:

> RESTORE DATABASE [somename] FROM  DISK = N'M:\path\Shares\55543f86-b817-4bc2-aaa3-baff0fc632c8.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,
>     MOVE N'xxx' TO N'M:\path\somename.mdf',
>     MOVE N'xxx_1' TO N'M:\path\FTIftrow_somename_1.ndf',
>     MOVE N'xxx_log_1' TO N'M:\path\somename_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

some more details on this restore, this restore also takes a awful lot of time, which is being asked here ..

[Restore database stuck at 100% progress](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/259392/31995)

Comment: What version? Include the output of `select @@version`.

Comment: What is the database context of your connection? Try adding "USE master" at the start of your script to ensure you're not accidentally in the DB context of the database you're restoring

Comment: The problem is that in your SSMS - you will have a default database set. Just change it to `master` and you should be good.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ,added version info

Comment: @KinShah ,@handyd issue is reproducibale even when i used `use master go` and then run the query

Comment: The `CROSS APPLY` is probably to blame. If you remove the CROSS APPLY, and *just* select from `sys.dm_exec_requests` I think you'll have better luck.

Comment: Can you add an example of the restore command? Does it happen with any database? Anything else noteworthy about the restored database or process?

Comment: @RandiVertongen i have added restore command being ran,yes happens with any restore.Actually this restore takes so much time, which is asked here  https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/259392/31995

Comment: I take it updating to SP3 CU4 did not help?

Comment: yes,it didnt help

Comment: What database context are you running the command in? Is there a way to replicate the behaviour? Could you trace your spid where you are running the commands from and see if anything else kicks in when getting the error?

Comment: @RandiVertongen master

Comment: Looks like you might not have [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization) enabled. Make sure the local security policy permits the SQL Server service account `Perform volume maintenance tasks`.

Comment: We have IFI enabled @DanGuzman